# Spring's ScriptUtils ignores code containing comments in dump

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mariadb, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to create a MariaDB database for unit tests and want to use Spring's `ScriptUtils` to execute the SQL file with the dump of tables and testdata. When I create the dump using HeidiSQL it inserts code-containing comments into the resulting sql-file, like the following to disable foreign key checks while loading the dump:

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
```

When I execute the dump script via HeidiSQL everything works out nicely. Using the following function in Java though:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void initializeForTest() throws Exception {
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    dsRoot = (DataSource) context.getBean("dataSourceRoot");
    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(dsRoot.getConnection(), new ClassPathResource("DROP_AND_CREATE_DATABASE.sql"));            
}
```

results in exceptions thrown because foreign key constraints fail, since the dump creates some tables with foreign key references to tables which still have to be created. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `postal_code` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country_alpha2` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`postal_code`,`country_alpha2`),
  KEY `country_alpha2` (`country_alpha2`),
  CONSTRAINT `cities_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_alpha2`) REFERENCES `countries` (`alpha2`)
);

/* ... */

CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `code` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `alpha2` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `alpha3` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `langCS` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `langDE` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `langEN` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `langES` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `langFR` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `langIT` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `langNL` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
  UNIQUE KEY `alpha2` (`alpha2`),
  UNIQUE KEY `alpha3` (`alpha3`)
);
```

Can I somehow execute the script without ignoring the code-containing comments?

Answer (score 1):

ScriptUtils JavaDoc the most usefull javadoc is the one of the

```
splitSqlScript(
      EncodedResource resource,
      String script,
      String separator,
      String commentPrefix,
      String blockCommentStartDelimiter,
      String blockCommentEndDelimiter,
      List<String> statements)` method, because it explains the meaning of the parameters:
```

> Split an SQL script into separate statements delimited by the provided
>   separator string. Each individual statement will be added to the
>   provided {@code List}.
>
> Within the script, the provided {@code commentPrefix} will be honored:
>   any text beginning with the comment prefix and extending to the end of
>   the line will be omitted from the output.
>
> **Similarly, the provided
>   {@code blockCommentStartDelimiter} and {@code
>   blockCommentEndDelimiter} delimiters will be honored: any text
>   enclosed in a block comment will be omitted from the output.**
>
> In addition, multiple adjacent whitespace characters will be collapsed
>   into a single space. ...

So after an second look at the util you will find the method:

```
public static void executeSqlScript(
      Connection connection,
      EncodedResource resource,
      boolean continueOnError,
      boolean ignoreFailedDrops,
      String commentPrefix,
      String separator,
      String blockCommentStartDelimiter,
      String blockCommentEndDelimiter)
```

It seams that you can not disable the block comment remove funktion, but you can configurer it to use other block comment delimiter:
So I think the trick is to use a `blockCommentStartDelimiter` that is different or does not occure at all.

```
ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(
    dsRoot.getConnection(), //Connection connection,
    new EncodedResource(new ClassPathResource("DROP_AND_CREATE_DATABASE.sql")), //EncodedResource resource,
    false,      //boolean continueOnError,
    false,      //boolean ignoreFailedDrops,
    "--",       //String commentPrefix,
    ";",        //String separator,
    "##/*",     //String blockCommentStartDelimiter,
    "*/##");    //String blockCommentEndDelimiter)
```

---

*BTW: other workaround: instead changing all comments via find and replace: add `set foreign_key_checks = 0;` at the beginning and `set foreign_key_checks = 1;` at the end.*

Answer (score 0):

We recently faced a similar issue when using Oracle hints in our SQL queries that are being executed by ScriptUtils.

Using the "fake" delimiters as suggested above solved it, but it seems to be an issue that should be fixed in ScriptUtils itself.

I opened a JIRA ticket on this at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-88

Thanks.